# How to get the Split value from collection

Tags: c#, collections, split

I have the following key value pair in an array, and am trying to extract and load them into a collection.

The below code is working but it can be optimized using linq:

```
        string _data = "Website=url:www.site1.com,isdefault:true,url:www.site2.com,isdefault:true";

        List<WebSiteAddress> _websiteList = new List<WebSiteAddress>() ;
        WebSiteAddress _website = new WebSiteAddress();

        string[] _websiteData = _divider[1].Split('=');
        string[] _WebsiteKeyValuePair = _websiteData[1].Split(',');

        for (int j = 0; j < _WebsiteKeyValuePair.Length; j++)
        {
            string key = _WebsiteKeyValuePair[j].Split(':')[0];
            string value = _WebsiteKeyValuePair[j].Split(':')[1];

            if (key.ToLower() == "url")
            {
                _initWebsite.Url = value;
            }
            else if (key.ToLower() == "isdefault")
            {
                _website.IsDefault = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                _websiteList.Add(_website);                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Seriously? CodeReview is still beta.

Comment: @AoiKarasu What does that have to do with anything? If it is not being used, it will never get out of beta.

Comment: Some people don't want to even try, its a simple enough question that OP is asking. He wants a linq implementation.

Comment: @AoiKarasu: that isn't relevant. CR is a mature site already, there's no reason why that would be an issue.

Comment: seriously? why my question is moving to CR? i would like the code to be in linq? is that too difficult to understand arggg.

Comment: What's wrong with beta sites?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
string _data = "Website=url:www.site1.com,isdefault:true,url:www.site2.com,isdefault:true";

    List<WebSiteAddress> _websiteList = _data
        .Split(new string[]{"url:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(site => site.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Where(site => site.Length > 1)
        .Select(site => new WebSiteAddress { Url = site[0], IsDefault = site[1].ToLower().Replace("isdefault:", "") == "true"})
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I'd love an explanation of this downvote....

Comment: some people just like to downvote for no reason..anyway thanks Dave for reply and after i run the code i see the following result `www.site1.com,isdefault:true,` `www.site2.com,isdefault:true`

Comment: `WebSiteAddress` object is empty

Comment: how does that work? so what i want to do is to load the data in the `websiteaddress` object and WebSiteAddress object has two props Url and IsDefault

Comment: http://dotnetfiddle.net/9MsQAG

Comment: That's exactly what this is doing - I've made a slight edit...

Comment: I know I took your code and put it on fiddle for you so you could prove it worked.

Comment: i have minor issue with the way its extracting from the collection and i have demonstrate here http://dotnetfiddle.net/RgQ8mE
so what is happening now that when i try to extract the data from collection its getting the last record please have a look at it,.